# Unable to save data into database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, twitter-bootstrap

I am inserting some data into database using run-time SQL query, but before that i am checking is there any record exists or not. following is my code

```
    protected void btnSignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                string strgender = "";
                if (Rb_Male.Checked)
                    strgender = "Male";
                else if (Rb_Female.Checked)
                    strgender = "Female";
                else
                {

                    lblMsg.Text = "Please Select Gender";
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }

                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmdcheck = new SqlCommand();
                cmdcheck.CommandText = "select * from [Users] where E_Mail='" + @tb_Email.Text + "'";
                cmdcheck.Connection = con;
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", tb_Email.Text);
                SqlDataReader drd = cmdcheck.ExecuteReader();
                if (drd.Read())
                {
                    lblEmail.Visible = true;
                    lblEmail.Text = "Email Already Exsits";
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    lblMsg.Text = "Account not created!!!";

                }
                else
                {
                    string strcmd = "insert into Users values ('" + @tbName.Text + "','" + @tbSName.Text + "','" + @tb_Email.Text + "','" + @tb_Pass.Text + "','" + @DropDownDay.Text + "','" + @DropDownMonth.Text + "','" + @DropDownYear.Text + "','"+ strgender +"')";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcmd, con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    lblMsg.Text = "Account created sussecfully";
                    lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                    clearallfields();
                }


            }
        }
        catch
        {

            lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblMsg.Text = "Account not created!!!";


        }


    }
    else
    {
        lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblMsg.Text = " * Enter Required Field(s)";
    }
}
```

The bellow part is working well in case if there no record associated with the particular email but if there is no record it goes to the else part and after executenonquery(); it goes to the catch part

```
if (drd.Read())
            {
                lblEmail.Visible = true;
                lblEmail.Text = "Email Already Exsits";
                lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblMsg.Text = "Account not created!!!";

            }
            else
            {
                string strcmd = "insert into Users values ('" + @tbName.Text + "','" + @tbSName.Text + "','" + @tb_Email.Text + "','" + @tb_Pass.Text + "','" + @DropDownDay.Text + "','" + @DropDownMonth.Text + "','" + @DropDownYear.Text + "','"+ strgender +"')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strcmd, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                lblMsg.Text = "Account created sussecfully";
                lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                clearallfields();
            }


        }
    }
    catch
    {

        lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblMsg.Text = "Account not created!!!";


    }
```

kindly help me out with this..

Comment: What are the exception details? use `Catch(Exception ex)` to see

Comment: the error is "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Answer (score -1):

Your insert statement doesn't specify which columns you want to add to the `Users` table.Place a breakpoint on the following line:

```
string strcmd = "insert into Users values ('" + @tbName.Text + "','" + @tbSName.Text + "','" + @tb_Email.Text + "','" + @tb_Pass.Text + "','" + @DropDownDay.Text + "','" + @DropDownMonth.Text + "','" + @DropDownYear.Text + "','"+ strgender +"')";
```

Take the value of `strcmd` and execute it in SQL Server Management Studio.You will see that it most likely fails.Fix the insert statement unti it works in SQL then copy it in your ASP.NET web application.

Also change your catch block and inspect the exception you're getting:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
```